# How to convert 5 1D arrays to a 2D array

Tags: java, netbeans

So i have to create a bingo board which i have done so, don't mind the long code it's repetitive for the first column method. So i wanna convert these 5 1D arrays to 1 2D array so i can check for a bingo. Could someone explain to me in detail how i would convert these 5 arrays to 1 2D array, or if it's possible to check 5 1D arrays.

```
package bingo;

import static java.rmi.Naming.list;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import static java.util.Collections.list;
import java.util.List;

public class Bingo {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {           
        int[][] card1 = new int[5][5];            
        int[] column1 = new int[5];
        int[] column2 = new int[5];
        int[] column3 = new int[5];
        int[] column4 = new int[5];
        int[] column5 = new int[5];

        column1(column1);
        System.out.println("");
        column2(column2);
        System.out.println("");
        column3(column3);
        System.out.println("");
        column4(column4);
        System.out.println("");
        column5(column5);
        System.out.println("");
        cardofzeros(card1);
        for (int i = 0; i < card1.length; i++) {    
            for (int j = 0; i < card1.length; i++) {    
            }
        }    
    }

    public static void column1(int[] column1) {
        int[] colm = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

        List l = new ArrayList();
        for (int i : colm) {
            l.add(i);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(l);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("|" + l.get(i));
        }

    }

    public static void column2(int[] column2) {
        int[] colm2 = {16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30};

        List l = new ArrayList();
        for (int i : colm2) {
            l.add(i);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(l);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("|" + l.get(i));
        }

    }

    public static void column3(int[] column3) {
        int[] colm3 = {31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45};

        List l = new ArrayList();
        for (int i : colm3) {
            l.add(i);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(l);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("|" + l.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void column4(int[] column4) {
        int[] colm4 = {46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60};

        List l = new ArrayList();
        for (int i : colm4) {
            l.add(i);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(l);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("|" + l.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void column5(int[] column5) {
        int[] colm2 = {61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75};

        List l = new ArrayList();
        for (int i : colm2) {
            l.add(i);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(l);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("|" + l.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void cardofzeros(int[][] card1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                card1[i][j]=0;
                System.out.print("|"+card1[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Can't you just use the 2D array _as is_?

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] first = null;
int[] second = null;
int[] third = null;
int[] fourth = null;
int[] fifth = null;


int[][] arr2d = new int[][]{first , second , third , fourth , fifth};
```